# SDF file always being created as read only after installation on Windows Mobile

Tags: installation, windows-mobile, sql-server-ce, windows-ce

My windows mobile app has a local database file (`database.sdf`). The file that is created when the user installs the CAB file in their device. The installation works fine but when I try to open the SDF with Query Analyzer or when the app tries to access the database I get a message.

> "Access to the database file is not allowed" (25039)

When I checked the permissions using Windows Explorer (the device is docked), the file is marked Read Only. If remove the Read Only checkbox everything works fine, I can open, edit and add records to the database.

How I can make the file not Read Only by default?

Answer (score 2):

You could verify the attribute programmatically during start-up of your application. In C#/.netcf it would be:

```
if (File.GetAttributes(path) & FileAttributes.ReadOnly == FileAttributes.ReadOnly)
    File.SetAttributes(path, File.GetAttributes(path) & ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answer provided by yms, I would try to figure out why the file is being created as ready-only in the first place.

Is it created via some custom installer dll you added to the installation process? Or is it packaged up into the .CAB file via cabwiz or an installer project in VS?

If it's the former, check the source code of that installer library.
If it's the latter, check the source files. If you include the SDF in your Visual Studio project and have the project checked into some type of source control, it's likely that while it's checked into the source repository it's read-only on disk when it get's packaged up into the .CAB.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but if Andrew is actually using the .netcf, it doesn't have File.GetAttributes.  Instead he should use

```
        FileInfo info = new FileInfo(pathToFile)
        if ((info.Attributes & FileAttributes.ReadOnly) == FileAttributes.ReadOnly)
            info.Attributes &=~ FileAttributes.ReadOnly;
```